# my custom cursor code is not working in IE

Tags: css

This code is working great in firefox n chrome but not in Internet Explorer.
Please me some solution.

```
    <style>
    div.cursor_green
    {
    cursor: url(pncl_green.png), auto;
    }
   </style>
```

Comment: Mixing CSS with jQuery!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your image in cur format that work great.

```
<style>
div.cursor_green
{
cursor: url(pncl_green.cur), auto;
}
</style>
```